# Using double and single quotes in wpdb select

Tags: mysql, wordpress, case

I'm trying to construct a wp query that creates a string for each record:

```
$ttr_a = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT CONCAT(
    '"TR4":"', 
    t2.TaxAccount, 
    '", "', 
    CASE    WHEN t1.TypeID = '1' THEN '"TR6":"Text A", ' 
            WHEN t1.TypeID = '2' THEN '"TR6":"Text B", ' 
    ELSE 
        CONCAT('"TR6":"', t1.NewID, '", ')
    END
) 
AS TID
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "table2 t2 
    ON t1.NewID = t2.TaxCode 
WHERE ID = " . $ID);
```

This query works fine in phpMyAdmin but the double quotes break the wpdb query. Is there some way to escape these? I've tried replacing with apostrophe and escaping the double qoutes with a double quote but nothing seems to work. If there are syntax errors here, please ignore them as I've just extracted what is needed, my sql query does work in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a prepared statement here if at all possible.  If that be not possible, then to escape literal double quotes inside a string defined with double quotes, try escaping the literal ones with backslashes:

```
$ttr_a = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT CONCAT(
    '\"TR4\":\"', 
    t2.TaxAccount, 
    '\", \"', 
    CASE    WHEN t1.TypeID = '1' THEN '\"TR6\":\"Text A\", ' 
            WHEN t1.TypeID = '2' THEN '\"TR6\":\"Text B\", ' 
    ELSE 
        CONCAT('\"TR6\":\"', t1.NewID, '\", ')
    END
)
AS TID
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN " . $wpdb->prefix . "table2 t2 
    ON t1.NewID = t2.TaxCode 
WHERE ID = " . $ID);
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim. That works but didn't provide the format I needed. I'm going for plan B... building the string in a [tag:foreach] loop. Very useful to learn how to use [tag:CONCAT] and [tag:CASE] though.